# Query multiple collections Arangodb

Tags: arangodb, aql

```
FOR col_name IN ['col_1', 'col_2']

FOR d IN FULLTEXT(col_name, 'label', @value)

RETURN d
```

does not works

but

```
FOR d IN FULLTEXT('col_1', 'label', @value)

RETURN d
```

works fine

I am using arango 3.4.2-1

Answer (score 4):

in general you can query two collections like this:

```
FOR col1doc IN col_1
  FILTER col1doc.foo == 'bar'
    FOR col2doc IN col_2
      FILTER col1doc.joinfield == col2doc.joinfield
RETURN {col1doc: col1doc, col2doc: col2doc}
```

as its [documented in the AQL manual for joins](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/AQL/Examples/Join.html)

Please note that simple string equalities can be done using `FILTER`s and don't need fulltext indices.

To the old fulltext index for two collections you can use subqueries like this:

```
let col1Documents = (FULLTEXT(col_1, 'label', @value))
let col2Documents = (FULLTEXT(col_2, 'label', @value))

RETURN CONCAT(col1Documents, col2Documents)
```

The more modern way to achieve this would be [to use ArangoSearch views](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Views/ArangoSearch/) which can handle numerous collections.

Comment: Thanks for this! This works fine but if there is no data in collection 2, nothing is returned, even though collection 1 has data. 

How do I get the fields from col1doc to return even if col2doc has no data?